# Dynamically generated text [Visual Basic]

Tags: vb.net

I have a question. I want to dynamically (I don't know if it is the right word for it) generate text in a textbox. What I mean is if in my textbox I want to have a word "CAT", when I press button it will generate it like this: First letter C so it will go through 0123456789ABC and will stop at C (yes i want to see that it started from 0 so it looks like it was decoding or something like that) then it will go for A - 0123456789A - and then for T 01....RST etc. Letter by letter or all start at once. Anyone have some idea how to make it ? I work in MS VB 2010 Express

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here but you could store an array holding up the characters you want and whenever a word is typed you look into this array from index 0 to your matching char's index.

Comment: what have you tried so far and why are stuck? BTW: something like this would an annoying way to input text.

Comment: i want something like a "keygen" that will look like key is decoded of something (but it is only visual effect)
For example code 3 4 5 will appear like this (each line is a new step)
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 4 4
3 4 5
Or another way: i want those lines appear in my textbox (each line changes every 0,5s until it reaches last line)

Comment: Fake keygen? I wonder what the purpose of that would be. Anyway, look into loops and delays and post a code that you tried.

Comment: the thing is that i even don't know how to start... if someone could help me it would be great, i just want a piece of code : another example
1.Textbox + button
2.Hitting button makes timer start
3.Every second a new numbers appear in textbox:
1st second : 0 0 0, 
2nd second  : 1 1 1,
3rd second : 1 1 2 and so on... I think you should understand me now.

Comment: I would suggest a delay of much less than a second. In your example of CAT the first character would display correctly after 13 seconds, the second after a further 11 seconds and the 3rd after a further 30 seconds. Total 54 seconds....

Comment: That was just an example :P So anyone can help me how to change Textbox.text every timer tick ?